# How to mount image file without root?

Tags: root-access, file-system, mount, factory-image

In rooted android phone, ext4 image file is mounted using these commands in android terminal :

```
  #  mknod    /dev/block/loop52  b 7 0 
  #  losetup  /dev/block/loop52  /sdcard/ext1.img
  #  mkdir /mnt/ext
  #  mount -t ext4 -o rw,noatime  /dev/block/loop52  /mnt/ext
```

I have an ext4 image file stored in sdcard.
How can I mount the ext4 image file in my non rooted android phone or Is there any other way to access it ?

Comment: You cannot access block devices without root access. Some explanation here: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/220020/218526