# Using a Partitioned drive on an Android TV

Tags: partitions, android-tv, smart-tv

I've got a partitioned drive - A USB drive, where i've got 2 of the partitions formatted ext3, one of the partitions as a FAT32, and the last one as FAT12. I wanted to access the FAT32 partition using an Android TV, however, the TV gives an error message "Unrecognised USB". Is there a way I could access individual partitions using the TV?

(PS: It is a MI TV)

Comment: Are you sure the HDD works at all when connected to MI TV? Such devices usually don't provide much power so the HDD may fail to start because of insufficient power. Use an active powered USB hub in between or HDDs with own power supply to avoid such problems.

Comment: @Robert, sorry, forgot to mention, I'm using a USB drive. Btw, when you mentioned HDD, I just remembered that my TV seems to support Partitioned HDD disks just fine. This is really wierd. However all the partitions on that HDD were FAT32, so I think that could be the difference.

Comment: android only provides 1st partition, repartitioning should work

Comment: @alecxs, The TV simply tells me the drive format cannot be understood, Does not even gives me the first partition :(  ... Android is a linux, it must be able to recognise and read ext3, which is the first partition. And in the case I mentioned in my initial comment, it perfectly recognised all of the partitions. I'm bit disinclined to repartition the drive, since it'll need me to reconfigure certain extra things as well.

Comment: @alecxs So, Is repartitioning, the only way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How would you use your ext4 formatted thumb drive via OTG on Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/109362/how-would-you-use-your-ext4-formatted-thumb-drive-via-otg-on-android)

Comment: @alecxs, The linked question didn't help :( Root access isn't there, I checked using adb.

Comment: @alecxs, sorry for the incredibly late reply; here is the screenshot: https://imgur.com/5NLIKa4.png

Comment: should be possible to root with this tool
https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/3786991

Comment: @alecxs, I know I'm being really picky, but I don't want to root TV either. I'll try repartitioning my drive.