# Storing files in a F2FS SD card

Tags: sd-card

I recently made my SD card F2FS. After that, it is not showing in my file manager or on my PC. How can I store files like photos, videos, and documents on my SD card?

Apps and their data are stored properly on the SD card, but I want to store pictures and videos as well on my SD card. Any solution?

Comment: @alecxs You mean Android requires FAT32, exFAT, NTFS for expose a folder via MTP, right? Because MTP as a protocol should be file-system independent, so Windows is not able to recognize if the data an MTP device exposes come form a specific file-system.

Comment: @Robert right, although Internal Storage is made available via MTP too

Comment: [How would you use your ext4 formatted thumb drive via OTG on Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/220020/218526)

Comment: but my ask is, how can i store both applications and media files on sd card in android?