# How to show configure mount ext2 ext4 formatted SD card partitions in android file manager?

Tags: external-sd, file-system, mount, ext2

How to show configure mount ext2 ext4 formatted SD card partitions in android file manager?

As fat32 fiile system don't support files more than 4 gb I have to take backup  before after rooting for safety backup of system boot userdata  through twrp or DD if  command which saves files in sd card and the files of twrp images of userdata  mmcblk0 is more than 8GB-15GB and it requires to format sd card to ext2. As in adb shell or fastboot we can write on ext2 formatted partion is micro sd card

But ext2 ext4 file system ( I formatted partitioned with mini partition tool) is not readable in windows PC and when I inserted booted android 6.0 and open the android self file manager or xplore or.solid explorer or settings storage  without rooting it shows only reads  the first partition of fat32 but it don't shows the second partition there and.even in settings storage as it's not mounting reading the  ext2 ext4 partition and mounting it.  Firstly I have to read  the sd card and copy the images file on pc which is unreadablle unmountable in  android and windows both

I know we can do adb pull command and copy it to pc directly but I want to change file system of external sd card to ext2 or ext4 so that if I download big videos or create any big size files more than 4gb then it can save it fastly and secure in ext2 or ext4 file system

My queries :-

Q1. Can we use configure SD card second partition ext2 or ext4 formatted  for moving apps as it move default to first partition through SM or PM commands can second app be used only in link2sd can't we manualy through adb shell configure it or format  first or second partition as internal memory

Q2. So my question is how through any app or adb shell command I can mount or make sd card second partition ext2 or ext4 file system mountable readable in my android 6.0 mobile phone. Any way to edit FUSE bind in boot.init without rooting or any other way apps  to make it readable.kindly guide steps as I am novice new to android adb and programming commands

Thanks for your precious time advice opinion suggestion and sharing knowledge.

Comment: Did you try [Mix explorer](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/app-2-2-mixplorer-v6-x-released-fully-featured-file-manager.1523691/page-1771#post-84578187)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read ext4 filesystem without mounting on a non-rooted device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/219474/how-to-read-ext4-filesystem-without-mounting-on-a-non-rooted-device)