# What file systems can I use with my SD card on a Samsung A10S?

Tags: samsung, sd-card, file-system, linux

I'm using a Samsung A10S phone. I use Arch Linux, no Windows, and I want my phone's SD card to be highly compatible with my PC. The default SD format seems to be vFAT which disallows many special characters in file names that are no problem on a Linux machine (`:`, `*`, `?`, `"`). I've tried formatting the SD card with EXT4 & EXT3 but when I put it back into the phone, it seems to be unable to work with the card and made me format it. There was no option as to what file system would be used and the card is now vFAT. I've tried looking online for possible file systems to use with the A10S but to no avail.

What file systems are compatible with the Samsung A10S? If there are others besides vFAT, what would be best for working with a Linux system?

Edit: 1 big reason I wanted `ext4` instead of `vFAT` is because I wanna get rid of the problem of certain disallowed special characters in `vFAT` so I'd like something without those restrictions.

Comment: for large files exFAT is recommended `mkfs.exfat`

Comment: @alecxs I've checked `exFAT` and it has problems with some special characters in file names as I've clarified in an edit.

Comment: that is filtered per design from upper layer `sdcardfs` in order to keep file name compatibility for MTP protocol (Microsoft) and cannot overcomed with any file system type. Even your Internal Storage (*/sdcard*) which is underlaying f2fs/ext4 (*/data/media/0*) emulates that limitation for reason. indeed exFAT is (besides NTFS) the only alternative to FAT32 witch will solve the 4 GiB file size limitation issue for android. btw even `adb` has issues with special characters in file names, it's more a matter of transfering protocol than file system type

Comment: you can transfer files with sed extension for GNU tar *--transform='s/[^][A-Za-z0-9 !#$%&'$'\047''()+,.\/;=@'$'\136''_\`{}~'$'\177''-]/_/g'* to convert file names during unpack

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read ext4 filesystem without mounting on a non-rooted device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/219474/how-to-read-ext4-filesystem-without-mounting-on-a-non-rooted-device)

Comment: @alecxs No, and I'm using `rclone` to sync stuff from my PC to my phone

Comment: [SDCardFS](https://www.xda-developers.com/diving-into-sdcardfs-how-googles-fuse-replacement-will-reduce-io-overhead) can be either FAT32 or exFAT (only some devices ntfs-3g too)

Comment: https://github.com/rclone/rclone/issues/2633

Comment: so you can either bootloader unlock trip knox and factory reset your device then root it disable dm-verity vaultkeeper proca tima and compile custom kernel with vold-posix module (not sure how you will overcome sdcardfs) or auto rename your files with rclone

Answer (score 2):

I would second what @alecxs said, go for exFAT filesystem, that one will be compatible with all the OSes involved.

Check out [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61209/create-and-format-exfat-partition-from-linux) on how to convert it to exFAT.